# unable to run bat file commands in cmd

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd

When I try to run bat files I receive this message

[image]

My bat file code is:

echo %0
pause

only my system is windows 8.1 64bit

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little digging makes this appear that you've saved your file in Unicode format, and the three characters at the beginning are the UTF-8 encoding of the Byte Order Mark. Open your batch file in Notepad, make sure those characters are not visible, then save it using SAVE AS..., and make sure that the encoding pulldown is set to ANSI.

Comment: thank you very much for the rapid and well explained answer.

Comment: @user3438908 Futher suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @CraigYoung - thanks for linking to that; I should have thought to do that, myself - especially since that's where I got the info that let me identify the odd characters as the UTF-8 of the BOM.